# +ev.clientX === ev.clientX in WinJS (Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I'm working on implementing pinch zoom-in/out code.
I simply checked WinJS semantic zoom implementation
and found interesting code snippet.

Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0/js/ui.js

Line number: 30710, 30720

```
return {
   x: +ev.clientX === ev.clientX ? (ev.clientX - sezoBox.left - sezoPaddingLeft - sezoBorderLeft) : 0,
   y: +ev.clientY === ev.clientY ? (ev.clientY - sezoBox.top - sezoPaddingTop - sezoPaddingTop) : 0
};
```

Why there is `+ev.clientX === ev.clientX`?

Comment: The code would surely be clearer as `x: isNan(ev.clientX) ? 0 : (ev.clientX - sezoBox.left - sezoPaddingLeft - sezoBorderLeft)`

Comment: Aha. + has many meaning depending on its context. I totally agree with Juan. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unary `+` operator is used as a cast to a `Number`. It's a really obscure way of ensuring `ev.clientX` is a number.

My recommendation: don't use it.
I guess this guy really likes his one-liners. I doubt his colleagues agree with him.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to check whether `ev.clientX` is not a number.

```
x === x
```

Is equivalent to

```
!isNaN(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

They are checking if  `ev.clientX` is a number and that it is not `NaN`. If it is, they do a calculation, and otherwise, they are returning 0.

The unary plus operator `+` coerces any value to a number. So, if ev.clientX does not have type `number`, then `+ev.clientX !== ev.clientX`.

Also note that `NaN !== NaN`, so if `ev.clientX` is `NaN`, then it will return false.

Comment: Do you really need "evidently" in your answer? It's not as evident to people who aren't aware of what the unary `+` does

Answer (score 2):

`+variable` parses the variable to a number, eg:

```
var a = "1";
+a; // 1
```

So it's a check to se if `event.clientX` is a number:

```
var a = "1";
+a === a // false
```

`a` is a string.

```
var a = 1;
+a === a // true
```